# Distribution of values in a postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, distribution

I have a Postgresql table like

```
user_name | product_name       
----------+-------------
      tom | candle
     bill | candle
     bill | candle
      tom | pen
     bill | pen
```

And I'd like to know the distribution of candle sales, i.e. how many people bought just one candle, how many people bought two candles, etc.

I have tried to use Postgreql window functions but my head hurts :) 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html

Geoffroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71c34/1)

```
select quantity, count(*)
from (
    select user_name, count(*) as quantity
    from t
    where product_name = 'candle'
    group by user_name
) s
group by quantity
order by quantity
```